# Pointer to const static array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

For finite field math I store the corresponding addition and multiplication tables as statically typed integer arrays, e.g., for GF(4/8), I have

```
static const uint8_t GF4ADD[4][4] = {...};

static const uint8_t GF8ADD[8][8] = {...};
```

Now, at runtime, the program reads from a config file which field size is desired and should assign to a struct pointer the corresponding table:

```
struct obj data {
...
  uint8_t** table_add;
  uint8_t** table_mult;
...
};

switch(order) {
case 4:
  data.table_add = GF4ADD;
  data.table_mult = GF4MULT;
  break;
case 8:
  data.table_add = GF8ADD;
  data.table_mult = GF8MULT;
  break;
}
```

Of course, the above doesn't work, but it should give you the idea of what I am trying to accomplish. The main problem is that I don't know of which type I should declare the struct members, as the size of the tables is only known at runtime. Besides, I do not want to resort to a one-dimensional indexing of the tables only.

Thanks, Tom.

Comment: Sounds like you need to study *dynamic allocation*.

Comment: If you want to have either `uint8_t *[4] table_add;` and `uint8_t *[8] table_add;`, would putting them in a union type work?

Comment: Well, yes, sure. But the struct (and therefore its members) are declared  in a header and instantiated only afterwards. So the question is, how do I have to declare it in the header, as the size is not known at type of declaration.

Comment: The C language is problematic here, since it does not allow you to declare variable length arrays (VLA) at file scope. So if you need a struct with variable-length arrays to be accessible from multiple files, you will have to do some manner of work-around.

The most common way would be to "mangle" the data into a single dimension and calculate the index is run-time. That's an acceptable solution, if not "pretty". (Efficient C code is rarely pretty.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare it as you did, with pointers. After that, when you will get the `order`, you will be able to allocate dynamically the memory you will need.

---

**Simple example 1 (using pointer to pointer):**

```
struct{
    int ** table_add;
}data;


int main()
{
    unsigned int order;
    scanf("%u", &order);
    // create "order" pointers 
    data.table_add = malloc(order * sizeof(int *));
    // where each pointer points to "order" elements
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < order; i++)
        data.table_add[i] = malloc(order * sizeof(int));

    // fill with numbers
    int counter = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < order; i++)
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < order; j++)
            data.table_add[i][j] = counter++;

    // read result
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < order; i++){
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < order; j++)
            printf("%d ",data.table_add[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Simple example 2 (allocating 2D array):**

replace the start of the 1st example with:

```
    ...
    unsigned int order;
    scanf("%u", &order);
    // allocate memory for a 2D array
    data.table_add = malloc(sizeof(int[order][order]);
    // fill with numbers 
    ...
```

*As @Lundin mentioned, this way is more efficient. The reasons for this are 3 as I see it:*

1. **Size** - no need to allocate memory for pointers (saves `order * sizeof(int*)` )
2. **Time** - one call to `malloc` instead of `order + 1`
3. **Simpler code** (less `mallocs` --> less `frees` --> less errors)

---

In your case, you will need to fill the elements in a loop (looping over each element and assigning them, or looping over `order` elements and using `memcpy`)

Comment: Please note that this is not a 2D array and also very inefficient code, see [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: Of course. But I guess this is what OP had in mind. I'll add the option to malloc 2D array, but I think this the basic simple answer (and not surprisingly, inefficient).

Comment: 4. Data cache friendly (the main performance reason)  5. Heap fragmentation-friendly.

Comment: Please note however that you cannot use a pointer-to-pointer to point at a 2D array. `data.table_add = malloc(sizeof(int[order][order]);` will not work unless `table_add` is of type `int(*)[order]` or `int(*)[order][order]`.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. This was very insightful as I wasnt aware of this and it seems that is not that straightforward. Assuming I forget about my restriction with using the previously declared struct, but simply want to create a 2D array with memory that is consecutively allocated. In this case I can define

    int(*a)[order];
    a = malloc(sizeof(int[order][order]))

However, VLA is then allocated on the stack, isn't it? As it is usually the case with any array. Assuming that order is really large, how would I do it then?